# Write output to text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've checked and compare to other questions here but I didn't find a solution.
I open a tile text and I get from this file IP addresses but I can't write this information to a new text file.
My output file shows only the last line of my log. There is only this []

My second question is I'd like to group by the same IP addresses before I write it to a new text file.

```
import re

in_file = open("D:\BLOCK\log")
out_file = open("D:\BLOCK\output.txt", "w")

for line in in_file:
        ipki = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line )
        print(ipki) 

out_file.write(str(ipki))   
file.close() 




print(ipki) 
['70.31.28.181']
['70.31.28.181']
['70.31.28.181']
['130.43.58.196']
['130.43.58.196']
['130.43.58.196']
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: Because you set the variable "ipki" to the results of your findall() call every time you iterate. It's overwritten for every line, leaving you only the results from the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, your problem is that you keep replacing `ipki` in the `for` loop and only write its final value at the end. `re.findall` returns a list of zero or more matched strings - since your output file contains the string representation of an empty list (`"[]"`), it means that the last line of the input file had no match.

You could add processing to add found ip4 addresses to a master list, but since `re.findall` can process large blocks of text, its easier to read the entire file at once and let it do the lifting for you. Once you have the list, you can use `set` to get rid of duplicates before writing the result file.

```
>>> import re
>>> with open('log') as fp:
...     ip4addrs = set(re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', fp.read()))
... 
>>> with open('output.txt', 'w') as fp:
...     fp.write('\n'.join(ip4addrs))
... 
26
>>> print(ip4addrs)
{'130.43.58.196', '70.31.28.181'}
>>> print(open('output.txt').read())
130.43.58.196
70.31.28.181
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Only one thing it's not correct. Ip addresses from the 'log' aren't in order in the 'output.txt' file. Neither from the top nor from the bottom. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: It's random every time when I run this script. I don't wanna sort descending or ascending but these ip addresses should be in order from log.